# CSS Displaying element at the bottom of parent element

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains a background image that has a width of 100% and specified height.

I have a search ribbon that i want to appear aligned to the bottom of the image. I know i can do this with absolute positioning, but i try to avoid absolute where i can.

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ur1Mu7nYifRTwb7dTEej?p=preview

Im trying to emulate like here: https://www.airbnb.com/

HTML:

```
<div class="bk-image">
    <section class="ribbon">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name a city" class="city-name"/>
    </section>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bk-image {
  background-image: url(http://gratisography.com/pictures/219_1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.ribbon {
  height: 90px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align: center;
}

.city-name {
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `position` and `bottom`:

```
.ribbon {
    height: 90px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align: center;
    /* Add the following */
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

Comment: Glad that helped you. `:)`

Comment: Who said "try to avoid absolute" @OamPsy deeply confused.

Comment: Very true @Paulie_D anyway... don't know what to [say](https://media4.giphy.com/media/Yo3zioWlWFvlS/200.gif).

Comment: @Pangloss That's a LoL.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when the question explicitly asked for a solution that didn't use absolute positioning?

Comment: @Shaggy ask the OP. This is the best way.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, sorry, didn't mean to imply that it wasn't. It 100% is the best way to do it but, yeah, my question was directed at the OP.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a div that contains a background image that has a width of 100% and specified height.

Since all the heights are known, ***in this specific instance*** you can either add `margin-top` to the "ribbon" div of 510px (600px - 90px) or `padding-top` of 510px to the image div.

**Margin Top Example**

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bk-image {
    background-image: url(http://gratisography.com/pictures/219_1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
.ribbon {
    margin-top: 510px;
    height: 90px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align: center;
}
.city-name {
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bk-image">
    <section class="ribbon">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name a city" class="city-name" />
    </section>
</div>
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2hzswjfm/)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use absolute positioning and there's a possibility that the parent's height could change over time, you can achieve this with [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Set the `display` property of the parent element to `flex` and the `align-items` property to `flex-end`. You'll also need to give the child element a `width` of 100%. And don't forget to [prefix the flexbox properties as necessary](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#000;font:arial;margin:0;padding:0;}
.bk-image{
  align-items:flex-end;
  background:url(http://gratisography.com/pictures/219_1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  display:flex;
  height:600px;
}
.ribbon{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  height:90px;
  padding:30px;
  width:100%;
}
.city-name{
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.95);
  border:0;
  display:block;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 10px;
  width:100%;
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bk-image">
  <section class="ribbon">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name a city" class="city-name">
  </section>
</div>
```

---

Or, as [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) pointed out in the comments, if you set the `flex-direction` to `column`, you don't need to set the width of the child element.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;color:#000;font:arial;margin:0;padding:0;}
.bk-image{
  background:url(http://gratisography.com/pictures/219_1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  height:600px;
}
.ribbon{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  height:90px;
  padding:30px;
}
.city-name{
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.95);
  border:0;
  display:block;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0 10px;
  width:100%;
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bk-image">
  <section class="ribbon">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name a city" class="city-name">
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just use `flex-direction:column` and `justify-content:flex-end`. Then you don't need to set a width on the child - http://jsfiddle.net/yzykrfwf/

Comment: Good thinking :) I'll update my answer to include your version.